# For pollution, How does exposure time and intensity for air quality affect health? Particularly for fine particulates

Tags: air-quality

I'm curious about how fine particulates (like PM2.5) cause damage to the lungs. This summer there's been a lot of concern about outdoor air quality because of wildfires.

My initial guess would be that the damage it causes scales linearly with the amount of time someone is exposed and with the concentration of fine particulates in the air. Doubling the concentration of fine particulates doubles the damage done to the lungs and doubling the time of exposure to polluted air doubles the damage.

Some reading I've done suggests however, for healthy individuals with no asthma or other mitigating conditions, that it scales super-linearly with time and sub-linearly with concentration (being exposed for a long time to small amounts of particulates is worse than being exposed for a short time to high concentrations).

This suggests to me that for most people the outdoor particulate air pollution should be much less concerning than their indoor air quality. The particulate air pollution warnings really affect at risk groups with previous conditions that affect breathing. Is this the case? Are there any good studies about this? Or am I just thinking about this issue too simplistically?

Comment: Yes, chronic exposure, low level is bad (though high chronic is also bad...) - think second-hand smoke for someone living in a smoker's house.